# Program is exiting at the wrong time

Tags: java, loops

I've gotten my loop to work and exit when the value '999' is entered.

I'm not sure what to do from here as my program isn't functioning exactly how I want it to.

Currently, the loop is exiting after the values 'num1' 'num2' and 'num3' have been fulfilled. I'm wanting the program to exit as soon as the value '999' is entered; not when num1, 2 and 3 have all been entered.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAverage {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Please Enter the first number%n");
        float num1 = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.printf("Please enter the second number%n");
        float num2 = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.printf("Please enter the third number%n");
        float num3 = keyboard.nextFloat();

        float sum = (num1 + num2 + num3);               //calculates sum
        float average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;     //calculates average

        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
            if (num1 == 999 || num2 == 999 || num3 == 999) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.printf("Sum: %.0f %nAverage: %.2f", sum, average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it computed the average with no issue.

Comment: `if(num1 != 999) {`... code that you want to only run if num1 isn't 999 goes here ...`}`

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the program to end as soon as a value of `999` is entered, you can change your `main()` method to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("Please Enter the first number%n");
    float num1 = keyboard.nextFloat();
    if (num1 == 999) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.printf("Please enter the second number%n");
    float num2 = keyboard.nextFloat();
    if (num2 == 999) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.printf("Please enter the third number%n");
    float num3 = keyboard.nextFloat();
    if (num3 == 999) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    float sum = (num1 + num2 + num3);             // calculates sum
    float average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;     // calculates average

    System.out.printf("Sum: %.0f %nAverage: %.2f", sum, average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the way your code is currently written, the user will always be required to input 3 values due to not having any kind of conditionals attached.

I recommend using "System.exit" with conditionals to test if the value the user is inputting is 999. Try going from there to see what you can make happen.

Here is some [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)) regarding "System.exit" to help you gain a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is looping only once so what I think you'll need to do is change some aspects of code

```
public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1;
        float num2;
        float num3;
        while (true){ //This will run forever until we break the loop
            num1 = keyboard.nextFloat();
            if (num1 == 999){
                break;
            }
            num2 = keyboard.nextFloat ();
            if (num2 == 999){
                break;
            }
            num3 = keyboard.nextFloat ();
            if (num3 == 999){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("The average is: " + (num1 +num2+num3)/3);
        }
    }
}
```